# Import Shared Library in LabVIEW with big DLL-Header (doxygen code)

Tags: dll, dllimport, labview

I am using the "Import Shared Labrary" from LabVIEW, to create VIs for my C-DLLs. Some time ago I started using doxygen to document the functions in my DLL-Header. Since then the size of the header heavily increased and when I recently tried to use the "Import Shared Library" Fuction LabVIEW could not handle the header anymore.

Does anybody have any experience with this? Or can someone give me an advice? Is there a way to make LabVIEW ignore the comments in the header?

Comment: What makes you sure that it is the size to blame?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. "_...LabVIEW could not handle the header anymore_" is not enough.

Comment: The only limitation I know of the length of the strings is the max size of an array is max 32-bit signed integer, aka, really really big. Are you honestly bumping up against those kinds of limits? Maybe you are... have you tried it on 64-bit LabVIEW?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm not absolutly sure it's the size, but I really just added comments. I am going to try importing parts of the header, perhaps I will find an error. With "could not handle" I mean LabVIEW did not respond anymore or completly crashed.